# Help with javascript (if) statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, if-statement

```
$("#right").click(function(){
    $(".block").animate({"left": "+=500px"}, "slow");
});

$("#left").click(function(){
  $(".block").animate({"left": "-=50px"}, "slow");
});

//Control
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
       alert( "left pressed" );
       return false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
       alert( "up pressed " );
       return false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
       alert( "right pressed " );
       return false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { 
       alert( "down pressed " );
       return false;
    }
});
;
```

I am trying to figure out how to make the click function (Animate)
go into the keydown events below can anyone help me? Im new to javascript.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "go into"? Why don't you explain what you want to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the code inside the `if` block like so...

```
if (e.keyCode == 40) { 
  $(".block").animate({"left": "-=50px"}, "slow");
}
```

Alternatively, you can call the `click()` on `$('#left')`, which would trigger its event handler.